# Itertools within web_crawler giving wrong triples

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have written some code to parse name, link and price from craigslist. When I print the result, these are getting scraped as list. I tried like the pasted code below to get a workaround but it gives wrong triples specially when a value is none it gets the next available value from another triples and so on. For this reason, it is of no use in this case. Hope I'm gonna have any suggestion as to how I can get this accomplished whether it is Itertools or any other methods.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from itertools import zip_longest

Page_link="http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/search/rea?s=120"
def parsing_craigslist(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    title = tree.xpath("//p[@class='result-info']//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' result-title ')]/text()")
    link = tree.xpath("//p[@class='result-info']//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' result-title ')]/@href")
    price = tree.xpath("//p[@class='result-info']//span[@class='result-price']/text()")
    for i,j,k in zip_longest(title,link,price,fillvalue=None):
        print(i,j,k)

parsing_craigslist(Page_link)
```

Comment: see them seperate like, `title` on one line then `link` on another then `price` on a third? just use three `print` statements, or use `pprint`.

Comment: Thanks  Tadhg McDonald-Jensen for your answer. I'm dreadfully sorry to have not been able to clarify how the output should be. Now, you can see.

Comment: I have tried your scraping, it works, I use zip : `for i,j,k in zip(title,link,price):` what's your issue?

Comment: Thanks Tiny.D for your answer. The page contains 120 records and using zip i got 82 records. Zip function patches a lead wrongly, as in when it sees either of (title,link,price) the values is missing it takes the next available value. If you take a look you will see that after 16th record all the value of price mismatch with title and link. Thanks.

Comment: so the issue is that some of the fields are missing? if they were `None` you'd have no problem, missing means the pairing go out of sync.  How can you determine which pieces of data correspond to each other?

Comment: Thanks  Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, for you answer. Yes, exactly what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination is to avoid the difficulties that could arise in trying to match collections from two `xpath` queries using a `zip` by doing a depth-first search and then examining each entry, as here.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/search/rea?s=120').text
tree = html.fromstring(page)
rows = tree.xpath('.//li[@class="result-row"]')
for n, row in enumerate(rows):
    price = row.xpath('.//a/span/text()')[0][1:]
    link = row.xpath('.//p/a')[0]
    title = link.text
    url = link.attrib['href']
    print ('--->', title)
    print (price, ':', url)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Bill Bell, for your answer. It's a good alternative. As a beginner, It is hard for me to understand one thing in your script. In Price you used [0][1:]. What does [1:] mean specially when it gets placed after [0]. Excuse my ignorance. Gonna accept your answer in a while.

Comment: Oh, the numbers in the price are preceded by a symbol for rupees, which is a little difficult to deal with. We know what the currency is, so I arranged to leave it out.

Comment: Thanks for everything sir.

Comment: My pleasure! ---